# Creating a secure DNN portal without SSL

Tags: dotnetnuke

Right now I am testing DNN using a DNNDEV.ME environment. I have created a sub-domain as a parent portal (subdomain.dnndev.me).

What I want to test out is automatically displaying a login if the user is not logged in. I.e., I am trying to secure the subdomain for client use. I was toying around with both Host and Admin settings (Site Management, Page Management, respectively). The only thing I saw on Page Management was to "Secure" the page, but this requires selecting SSL in Host>Site Management. Those settings seem to require an SSL certificate. Even if I select SSL Enabled, I'm still not initially planning on installing SSL certificates on a small site.

What I am after is simply this: from the main site (dnndev.me) the user will click a link that leads to the subdomain (subdomain.dnndev.me). From there I want the user to register / login, so I would like the login page to popup immediately upon hitting the site to force login (or registration if it's a new user).

Basically, I want the entire subdomain to require authentication.  I did not see a site-wide setting for that.

Any thoughts? resources? examples?  Thanks!

Comment: Of course I mean other than making sure "All Users" is not selected in the Permission settings when you edit a page. I guess this alone would work if I only use a set of modules on a page that also use templates for their views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring the Page permissions to require the "registered users" role to view the page is pretty much the only way to do this right now.

You could write a custom module that was on all pages and popped up a login module, but really the page level permissions is the only way to do this properly in DNN.